# Return deafult value in SQL select statment searched value is not found

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to return default value in Select statement when WHERE clause is not met.
So basically, this query returns valid guid:

```
SELECT COALESCE(w.guid , gen_random_uuid()) as guid
        FROM MyTable w
        WHERE w.id = 108
        AND w.company IN (27);
```

But this doesn't find id 109, so it should generate new random uuid:

```
SELECT COALESCE(w.guid , gen_random_uuid()) as guid
        FROM MyTable w
        WHERE w.id = 109
        AND w.company IN (27);
```

But instead it returns nothing. How I can solve this?

Comment: is w.guid NULL for id = 109?

Comment: Why? If the row does not exist, what use is a `uuid`?

Comment: If there is no row at all then nothing is returned so coalesce won't do it - off the top of my head maybe your first query with a union all select gen_random_uuid() from X where not exists (select 1 where id = 109 and company in ....etc). If this was Oracle you'd select from dual, I can't remember now the equivalent in postgres

Comment: If this is part of a wider need to insert if the row isn't there the answer might be different - as @Adrian Klaver says - what are you doing with this selected UUID if not then inserting it as a new row for that Id and company (be careful what you ask as you may get an answer that is completely correct but completely pointless)

Comment: This is a part of bigger picture

Comment: Ah yep, thought it might be, and glad you got a nice (and elegant) answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get no uuid because no row is selected and nothing returned therefore.
This might solve your problem:

```
  SELECT coalesce(
    (select w.guid FROM MyTable w
        WHERE w.id = 109 AND w.company IN (27)
    ), 
    gen_random_uuid()) as guid;
```

Didn't test it on real data, but you get the idea i'm sure.

Answer (score 1):

Use a RIGHT JOIN on a sub select that creates the default value. Something like this (not tested, no data available):

```
SELECT 
    COALESCE( w.guid, G.guid ) AS guid 
FROM
    genius."attribute" w
    RIGHT JOIN ( SELECT gen_random_uuid()) G ( guid ) ON w.ID = 109 AND w.company IN ( 27 );
```